# SQL Keyword Logic

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am looking at some logic, and I cannot figure out how to make this work. Basically I have two strings of SQL. One has the keywords pingu and one has noot as seen below: This is stored in **KEYWORD1** - which is a temporary location

```
declare @teststring varchar(512) = '{KEYWORD}' 
select top 1 k.type 
from (values 

('pingu', '66'), ('noot', '66'))

k(word,type) where @teststring like '%' + k.word + '%' 

group by k.type 
HAVING COUNT(1) >=2
order by COUNT(1) desc
```

My other string has two keywords such as: Sponge and Bob. This is stored in **KEYWORD2** - which is a temporary location

```
declare @teststring varchar(512) = '{KEYWORD}' 
select top 1 k.type 
from (values 

('sponge', '66'), ('bob', '66'))

k(word,type) where @teststring like '%' + k.word + '%' 

group by k.type 
HAVING COUNT(1) >=2
order by COUNT(1) desc
```

Now when my staff use the program they have an option to enter some free text, they can enter anything e.g sponge went noob or pingu goes bob.

I then have a check which says if KEYWORD1 and KEYWORD2 is found, then do something else, otherwise continue. Which is fine effectively the below works!..

```
declare @teststring varchar(512) = '{KEYWORD}' 
select top 1 k.type 
from (values 

('KEYWORD1', '2'), ('KEYWORD2', '2'))

k(word,type) where @teststring like '%' + k.word + '%' 

group by k.type 
HAVING COUNT(1) >=2
order by COUNT(1) desc
```

This is all good as it takes one word from each and goes down the correct route. BUT.. what happens if you put in Sponge Bob in is that it breaks as its trying to find both sponge bob and pingu noot. But I almost want 3 routes so tp speak.

To say: If pingu noot exists then continue, otherwise if sponge bob exists continue or is pingu and bob exists continue or if sponge and noot exists continue

**JUST TO CONFIRM: I am using third party software, I cannot update or delete any tables**

Comment: I think what I want to know is if any two words in any two strings of text exists continue, otherwise if one word in two strings of text exists then don't continue.

Comment: Your questions isn't fully clear. The input I take it are - pingu noot, sponge bob, pingu bob and each of these inputs is coming as a string type of variable. Additionally you say there could be more words. Where is it you want to check if these two words are present? Is it a validation in table of two seperate columns (or) combination of columns?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code, explanations and examples for you. I also had to add some assumptions - maybe you have to alter the code if I got you wrong :-)

```
/* KeyWord 1 contains 2 phrases */
--One has the keywords pingu and one has noot as seen below: This is stored in KEYWORD1
DECLARE @KeyWord1_1 varchar(512)
DECLARE @KeyWord1_2 varchar(512)
SET @KeyWord1_1 = 'pingu'
SET @KeyWord1_2 = 'noot'

/* KeyWord 2 contains 2 phrases */
--My other string has two keywords such as: Sponge and Bob...
DECLARE @KeyWord2_1 varchar(512)
DECLARE @KeyWord2_2 varchar(512)
SET @KeyWord2_1 = 'sponge'
SET @KeyWord2_2 = 'bob'

/* Your input-variable */
--Now when my staff use the program they have an option to enter some free text, they can enter anything e.g...
DECLARE @teststring varchar(512)
SET @teststring = 'sponge went noot or pingu goes bob.'
-- EXAMPLES
--SET @teststring = 'sponge bob'
--SET @teststring = 'pingu noot'
--SET @teststring = 'pingu bob'
--SET @teststring = 'pingu bob'
--SET @teststring = 'noot bob'


DECLARE @done int
SET @done = 0 -- we will need this for the further IFs :-)

-- your requirement:
-- If pingu noot exists then continue (= when the two phrases of keyword are given)
--, otherwise if sponge bob exists continue  (= when the two phrases of keyword are given)
--or is pingu and bob exists continue  
--or if sponge and noot exists continue (also when pingu/sponge and noot/bob are given? (IF YES* IF NO**)
-- **NO would mean: A full keyword, it can be mixed but it must fit a first and a second phrase
-- *YES woudl mean: A whole keyword must be found, or a pharse from the first and the second keyword
-- In my example I will stay with _NO_
IF   (@teststring LIKE '%'+@KeyWord1_1+'%'  -- First Keyword - Full
  AND @teststring LIKE '%'+@KeyWord1_2+'%')
  AND @done = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'If pingu noot exists then continue'
    SET @done = 1;
END
IF (@teststring LIKE '%'+@KeyWord2_1+'%'  -- Second Keyword - Full
  AND @teststring LIKE '%'+@KeyWord2_2+'%')
  AND @done = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'otherwise if sponge bob exists continue'
    SET @done = 1;
END

IF   (@teststring LIKE '%'+@KeyWord1_1+'%'  -- First Keyword, first Phrase and
  AND @teststring LIKE '%'+@KeyWord2_2+'%') -- Second Keyword, second Phrase
  AND @done = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'pingu and bob exists continue'
    SET @done = 1;
END

IF (@teststring LIKE '%'+@KeyWord2_1+'%'  -- Second Keyword, first Phrase and
  AND @teststring LIKE '%'+@KeyWord1_2+'%') -- First Keyword, second Phrase
  AND @done = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'sponge and noot exists continue'
    SET @done = 1;
END

IF @done = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'and i still haven''t found, what i''m looking for...'
END

-- If you also want to check the order (to prevent "noot pingu" from working) you can try this:
SET @teststring = 'noot pingu'   -- not working
SET @teststring = 'pingu noot' -- it's okay
SET @done = 0

IF   (@teststring LIKE '%'+@KeyWord1_1+'%'  -- First Keyword - Full
  AND @teststring LIKE '%'+@KeyWord1_2+'%')
  AND @done = 0
  AND CHARINDEX(@KeyWord1_1,@teststring,1) < CHARINDEX(@KeyWord1_2,@teststring,1) -- that's the ticket...
BEGIN
    PRINT 'If pingu noot exists - IN THE CORRECT ORDER then continue'
    SET @done = 1;
END
```

Also consider this is just how you could make it work - it is not meant to be a complete solution.
It is no good way to ensure security and also check if your database is case sensitive!

Regards
tgr